# Is Rolle's Theorem true when the function..

Tags: calculus, derivatives, rolles-theorem

Is Rolle's Theorem true when the function is not continuous at the end points?

Suppose we define a function $f(x)=x$ for $0<x\leq 1$ and define $f(0)=1$ then it satisfies all the conditions of above theorem, except continuity at $x=0$. Is Rolle's Theorem true in such cases?

Comment: No, as your own example proves.

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine function in start/end of interval, so, formally, to have function not continuous, but you need $f(a+)=f(b−)$ to save Rolle's soul.

Comment: +1 for saving Rolle's soul. Funny phrase.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh. I was hoping to appreciate math, but appreciated humor, as always.

Answer (score 2):

We have $f(1)-f(0)=0.$ Suppose that Rolle's theorem is true. Then there is $t \in (0,1)$ such that

$$0=f'(t)=1,$$

which is absurd.